# Export dataframe from R to SAS

Tags: r, dataframe, sas

I have a data.frame in R, and I want to export it to a SAS file. I am using write.xport to do that. The column names are like:
`a.b.c, a.b.d, a.f.g, ...`

When I get the data in **SAS**, column names are like: a(1),a(2),..
How can I keep the original labels in exported SAS file?
I get the error:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In makeSASNames(colnames(df)) :
>     Truncated 119 long names to 8 characters.
>   2: In makeSASNames(colnames(df)) : Made 106 duplicate names unique.

Comment: You cannot use variable names longer than 8 characters in a SAS V5 transport file.  If you need longer names then you need a different output format.

Comment: Is there any other way to export those labels to SAS file?

Comment: Try using Haven package.  It can write sas datasets and also both the older SAS V5 transport files and the new V8 definition that SAS has macros to support.

Comment: Thank you. The length of my labels are too long: about 50 characters, I use write_xpt (data,path,Version=8), but I get the error: A provided column name is too long for the file format. Shall I save the colnames separately or there is a way to export them directly?

Comment: For SAS datasets the NAME of a variable (I think what you mean by label) can only be up to 32 characters.  But SAS datasets support a LABEL attribute for a variable that can be up to 256 characters long.  Just make shorter names for your variables and use the longer names as the labels.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the length, it seems your column names contain '.'-character? SAS doesnt allow for those kind of names. SAS uses the . to represent e.g. library.dataset -notation and it has many others uses. The colnames cannot contain many + or - or & -chars either.

So to summarize; make your column names SAS -compatible. See the [SAS documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000998953.htm) for more. 
SAS uses the column labels, which allow for more complexity, only for the purposes of outputting, afaik. Thus, if you want to manipulate data in SAS, you need to rethink your column names first.